# How to set seed value properly to a ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, random-seed

I am new to ML and running different classification models. What I observe is every time I run the model,I get slightly different results. I learnt online that it's about setting seed value. But I couldn't achieve reproducability?

The below is my code where I tried setting the seed value but it doesn't help

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
random.seed(1234)
param_grid = {'C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100],  
              'gamma': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001], 
              'kernel': ['linear','rbf','poly'],
              'class_weight':['balanced']}
svm=SVC()
svm_cv=GridSearchCV(svm,param_grid,cv=5)
svm_cv.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
y_pred = svm_cv.predict(X_test_std)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Can you help me understand how to set `seed` value so that everytime when I run the above code, I get the same result/accuracy/metric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit learn uses the numpy random seed. Therefore you should import numpy and set its random seed like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
```

(https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-set-the-global-random_state-in-scikit-learn/)

Comment: Thank you upvoted and marked as answer. So should I use this for each model? Or setting the seed once, will help me to reproduce the results at any time  for anyt model

Comment: @SSMK you can also refer FAQ - [How do I set a `random_state` for an entire execution?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution)

Comment: Hi, I tried this but still it doesn't work. I mean I defined `np.random.seed` in my Jupyter cell at the top

Comment: In the below cells, I executed code for classifiers like I have shown above. Should I pass this seed value as parameter to model anywhere?

Comment: As you can see in the link the seed starts from where you defined it. So if you have code like above, then you need to reset the seed to the same value before any of the function calls to get the same result.